# Csv file Loop works wrong

Tags: java, loops, csv

I am trying to write the test result in csv file by using BufferedWriter. The test duration for WAF5-H is 2 seconds. and WAF6-L is 5 seconds. 
My output file is:

```
Thu Feb 18 14:01:07 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
WAF5-H;
Thu Feb 18 14:01:08 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
WAF5-H;
Thu Feb 18 14:01:09 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
WAF5-H;
```

I expected:

```
Thu Feb 18 14:01:07 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;
Thu Feb 18 14:01:08 CET 2016;1;WAF5-H;
Thu Feb 18 14:01:08 CET 2016;2;WAF5-H;
```

until test end then the next job will begin.

```
for (int i = 0; i < convertedDifference; i++) {
    for (Job currentJob : NEHCalculator.addNewJobInitializeList()) {
        int testDevice = (DeviceGroups.DeviceAList.size() + DeviceGroups.DeviceBList.size()
            + DeviceGroups.DeviceCList.size() + DeviceGroups.DeviceDList.size());
        int times = (int) ((convertedDifference / currentJob.getInterval()) * testDevice);
        for (int t = 0; t < times; t++) {
            // until end of the test date.
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
            beginDate.getTime();
            // write the test date
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(cal.getTime()));
            bufferedWriter.write(';');
            // write the test total second begin with 0.
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(i));
            bufferedWriter.write(';');
            double j = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < currentJob.getNeededTestTime(); j++) {
                bufferedWriter.write(currentJob.getJobname());
                bufferedWriter.write(';');
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}

bufferedWriter.close();// Always close files.
```

The first for loop explain do the test until test ending time. (
   actual output violated this because it write down 0 2 times so it
   will continue until 13442.. . Normally I expected to see 3600 lines
   in my csv file.

The second for each loop get the selected job list.

Third for loop explains how many time testing will be occured. ( I
   entered 1 hour testing time and testing time will make every 15
   minutes and WAF 5H tests 4 devices. So 4*4*2 = 32 times I would like
   to see WAF5-H on the csv file.

Last for loop explains the needed time
   testing for each required machine. ( For WAF 5-H 2 seconds.)

Could someone please help me

Comment: the line `bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(i));` will write 0 as many times as the inner for loop runs (maybe you wanted to put `t` instead of `i` there). And you have an even inner loop (`for` using `j` that writes the job name and prints a new line. I think the result you get is pretty much the correct one for your code.

Answer (score 1):

try this: within your third loop a new line is inserted for each iteration

```
 for (int i = 0; i < convertedDifference; i++) {
            for (Job currentJob : NEHCalculator.addNewJobInitializeList()) {
               int testDevice = (DeviceGroups.DeviceAList.size() 
                                 + DeviceGroups.DeviceBList.size()
                                 + DeviceGroups.DeviceCList.size() 
                                 +  DeviceGroups.DeviceDList.size());
              int times = (int) ((convertedDifference / currentJob.getInterval()) * testDevice);
              for (int t = 0; t < times; t++) {
                 // until end of the test date.
                 cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
                 beginDate.getTime();
                 // write the test date
                 bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(cal.getTime() +
                    ';' + String.valueOf(i) + ';'));

               //double j = 0; no need to declare double var
              for (int j = 0; j < currentJob.getNeededTestTime(); j++) {
                  bufferedWriter.write(currentJob.getJobname()+ ';');
                ////////////////////////////////////
                /// issue  
                ////////////////////////////////////
                // bufferedWriter.newLine();
              }
          }
      }// end of currentjob loop
     bufferedWriter.newLine(); // ok hear
 }// end first for loop
```

Comment: I did the change that you recommended but the result is seen as follows
Thu Feb 18 15:48:42 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;WAF5-H;
Thu Feb 18 15:48:43 CET 2016;0;WAF5-H;WAF5-H;
Thu Feb 18 15:48:44 CET 2016;3;WAF5-H;WAF5-H;
Thu Feb 18 15:48:45 CET 2016;3;WAF5-H;WAF5-H;
Thu Feb 18 15:48:46 CET 2016;3;WAF5-H;WAF5-H;
Thu Feb 18 15:48:47 CET 2016;3;WAF5-H;WAF5-H;

Comment: why do u increment  i++; inside a for loop ?

Comment: Meaningless.. I forgot to delete it. I deleted i++

Comment: so let's streamline your spec for a best solution, the bufferW.newLine() should be out of the current job loop, which means that for each currentjob you'll display XXXX;XXXX;X;WAF5-H; (and only here perform new line )

Comment: Sorry I could not accept your answer, it could not generate the output that I expected.